# meteor update from 0.6.4.1 to 0.6.5

Tags: meteor

in ~/.meteor/package/ folder all package.js files has only this:

// This file is included for compatibility with the Meteor 0.6.4 package downloader.

and nothing more.

Where is the package.js code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The package system has changed.

You will find the auto-generated file you're refering to under:

```
/packages/name_of_your_package/.build/
```

As for where the actual 'package.js' file is, it's under

```
/packages/name_of_your_package/
```

As per the source code that's building these files for you:

```
  // Pre-linker versions of Meteor expect all packages in the warehouse to
  // contain a file called "package.js"; they use this as part of deciding
  // whether or not they need to download a new package. Because packages
  // are downloaded by the *existing* version of the tools, we need to
  // include this file until we're comfortable breaking "meteor update" from
  // 0.6.4.  (Specifically, warehouse.packageExistsInWarehouse used to check
  // to see if package.js exists instead of just looking for the package
  // directory.)
  // XXX Remove this once we can.
  builder.write("package.js", {
    data: new Buffer(
      ("// This file is included for compatibility with the Meteor " +
       "0.6.4 package downloader.\n"),
      "utf8")
  });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: user1744153, you're welcome! If this is the answer to your question, please click the green checkmark near my post :D Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what i want is find the main packages. As an example i want to find where is package email for version 0.6.5. in my ~/.meteor directory under package/. The email package is there but the package.js say "// This file is included for compatibility with the Meteor 0.6.4 package downloader." and i can´t find where is the package.js for version 0.6.5 and yet my project works with version 0.6.5.

Comment: Ahh... I see. Well I'm a bit surprised you're seeing the stubs straight under /packages but in any case, have a look at .meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages (it's a hidden folder). This is where the built-in packages are stored.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, perhaps i don't explain my self right, i will try again if you don't mind. When i update to 0.6.5 in my home directory (/Users/myusername/.meteor) i should be seeing all the package with came with meteor. I'm not looking for packages with are under my project and under my package folder project. Imagine i install meteor for the first time. Where should i find all the original packages with came with meteor framework? I presume it is under my home folder under .meteor/packages not my project folder.

Comment: /Users/username/.meteor is the warehouse - it stores copies of meteor versions so that you can easily switch between releases at the prompt. Packages are tracked independently of releases, so that things can stay consistent between a team running multiple releases. So yes, your current packages that came with meteor sit there, somewhere under something like /Users/stephantual/.meteor/packages/backbone/ffb277a421551eb95e6855ad9637800676ec4a37, but as the hash indicates, that's probably not the right way to go and explore :D  ...

Comment: (continued)... if you want to the core package pristine from meteor 065, easiest way is probably to git checkout that release after cloning the repo in a separate folder - does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. But that is an alternative that i don't want for now. I was expecting to find the core packages when i install meteor for the first time or when i update meteor. Thanks.

Comment: ... but ... but ... but :D If it's the first time you install, all the packages are under ./meteor under your project folder (after you have executed meteor create). Meteor does all that for you.... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I use meteor since the beginning and meteor always have the core package in one location and now i don't find it. Where it is supposed to find it (/Users/myusername/.meteor) i just find what i have been told you and i don't find the core package of version 0.6.5.